# How To Pass If Condition To Excel VBA Text Join?

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function, textjoin

How does one pass an if condition in Textjoin into the VBA equivalent?
ie. my working formula in Excel currently is:

```
=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IF(M1:M100=1,N1:N100,""))
```

This is to join rows in column N if the flag is set in column M.

What I am trying to get is to replicate this in VBA, something like:

```
abc = WorksheetFunction.TextJoin(" ", True, IF(Range(M1:M100)=1,Range(N1:N100),"")
```

But can't seem to work out how to pass the criteria to the worksheet function.
Any ideas?

I guess the question also relates to WorksheetFunction.Filter, on how you can pass a filter condition to it, something like:

```
 WorksheetFunction.Filter(Range("M:M"), Range("N:N") & "=1", False)
```

I say this as if I can work out the filter, I can probably just pass that range to the text join directly.

Thanks!

Comment: Try: `abc = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("TEXTJOIN("""",TRUE,IF(M1:M100=1,N1:N100,""""))")`. BTW, for those who haven't got 365, this is an array formula in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

### `TEXTJOIN` With an If Conditioned Array in VBA

[image]

- The image shows that your formula isn't quite correct. By introducing the `If` statement, the second argument has become irrelevant. You have chosen `True` to skip blanks but they won't be skipped. You can cover for it with another (nested) `If` statement.
- The three examples in the following procedure show how you can use a VBA version of your idea. The first two are mostly based on the `Evaluate` method, while the third uses the function below.
- I don't have Office 365, so you could expect another answer using those new functions it contains.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    With ActiveSheet
        
        ' 1.) Evaluate
        Debug.Print .Evaluate("=TEXTJOIN("""",FALSE," _
            & "IF(M1:M100=1,IF(N1:N100="""","""",N1:N100),""""))")
        
        ' 2.) Worksheet Function + Evaluate
        Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.TextJoin("", False, _
            .Evaluate("IF(M1:M100=1,IF(N1:N100="""","""",N1:N100),"""")"))
        
        ' 3.) Function (UDF)
        Debug.Print TextJoinIf(.Range("M1:N100"), 2, 1, 1, "")
    
    End With
End Sub
```

- You can use the following function in VBA or if you have Office prior to 2019, also as a UDF. Skipping blanks is assumed.

```vb
Function TextJoinIf( _
    ByVal rg As Range, _
    ByVal ConcatColumn As Long, _
    ByVal FlagColumn As Long, _
    ByVal Flag As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal Delimiter As String = " ") _
As String
    Const ProcName As String = "TextJoinIf"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = rg.Value
    Dim sr As Long
    Dim rString As String
    For sr = 1 To rg.Rows.Count
        If Data(sr, FlagColumn) = Flag Then
            If Len(Data(sr, ConcatColumn)) > 0 Then
                rString = rString & Data(sr, ConcatColumn) & Delimiter
            End If
        End If
    Next sr
    If Len(rString) > 0 Then
        TextJoinIf = Left(rString, Len(rString) - Len(Delimiter))
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```